# Can I reinterpret cast in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, casting, glsl

In C++ you can take a pointer of an unsigned int, and cast it to a pointer to a signed int (`reinterpret_cast`).

```
unsigned int a = 200;
int b = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&a));
```

I need to store an `int` generated in a shader as an `unsigned int`, to be written to a texture with an unsigned integer internal format. Is there any similar alternative to C++'s reinterpret_cast in GLSL?

Comment: [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Constructors) says *"Conversion between [int and uint] is guaranteed to preserve the bit pattern"*, does that satisfy your needs?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Ah I feel dumb for not catching that. Yes, that was the answer. Should I leave this question up or take it down since the answer was so simple?

Comment: @Spektre In my program it is an unsigned int... I don't know why I put char in the example, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ (pre-20), signed and unsigned integers are permitted to be represented in very different ways. C++ does not require signed integers to be two's complement; implementations are allowed to use ones complement, or other representations. The only requirement C++ has on signed vs. unsigned is that conversion of all non-negative (or trap) signed values to unsigned values is possible.

And FYI: your code yields UB for violating the strict aliasing rule (accessing an object of type X through a pointer to an unrelated object of type Y). Though this is somewhat common in low-level code, the C++ object model does not really allow it. But I digress.

I brought up all the signed-vs-unsigned stuff because GLSL actually *defines* the representation of signed integers. In GLSL, a signed integer is two's complement. Because of that, GLSL can define how conversion from the entire range of unsigned value goes to signed values and vice-versa, simply by preserving the bitpattern of the value.

And that's exactly what it does. So instead of having to use casting gymnastics, you simply do an unsigned-to-signed conversion, just as you would have for float-to-signed or whatever:

```
int i = ...
uint j = uint(i);
```

This conversion preserves the bit-pattern.

Oh, and C++20 seems to be [getting on-board with this too](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r1.html).

Answer (score 0):

GLSL does not support this kind of casting (nor does it support pointers at all).  Instead, in GLSL you construct values of a different type with constructor-style syntax:

```
int a = 5;    // set an int to a constant
uint b = uint(a);   // "cast" that int to a uint by constructing a uint from it.
```